Contract interaction failed
I tried to launch a smart contract with remix eth... Meta mask said failed but funds are gone. Verified on either scan transaction is there still but no funds? Anybody have any clue what I did wrong or if I can recover the funds?

share the tx and more details for better answers

If you were following a YT guide to deploy a front running bot it is very likely you have been scammed.

Failed smart contract deployments can result in gas fees being deducted even if the transaction doesn't succeed. Unfortunately, these fees are non-refundable. Consider reaching out to MetaMask support for further assistance. In the future, ensure thorough testing before deployment to mitigate such risks.
